# Mysqli and PDO combined with Javascript and Ajax... possible?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Simple question from a noob programer. Thinking of several different styles and features to a project i have for a  social website. question is this...
can you combine mysqli and PDO style programs?

having difficulty inserting data into database with php, ajax and javascript modules. it says "success" but doesnt insert the info with mysqli. i HAVE used PDO successfully. but my code looks right... it has the same syntax as the tutorial i am looking at with mysqli. this is the code...

```
<!-- ********************************** -->
<!-- *********** signup.php *********** -->
<!-- ********************************** -->
<?php
session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: message.php?msg=NO to that weenis");
    exit();
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
        exit();
    }
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        $cryptpass = crypt($p);
        include_once ("php_includes/randStrGen.php");
        $p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
        $to = "$e";                          
        $from = "auto_responder@yoursitename.com";
        $subject = 'yoursitename Account Activation';
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>yoursitename Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com"><img src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="yoursitename" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursitename Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
function openTerms(){
    _("terms").style.display = "block";
    emptyElement("status");
}
/* function addEvents(){
    _("elemID").addEventListener("click", func, false);
}
window.onload = addEvents; */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("includes/template_header.php"); ?>
<div id="pageMiddle">
  <h3>Sign Up Here</h3>
  <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("includes/template_country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
        View the Terms Of Use
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
      <h3>Web Intersect Terms Of Use</h3>
      <p>1. Play nice here.</p>
      <p>2. Take a bath before you visit.</p>
      <p>3. Brush your teeth before bed.</p>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
</div>
<?php include_once("includes/template_bottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
<!-- ********************************** -->
<!-- *********** activation.php ******* -->
<!-- ********************************** -->
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['p'])) {
    // Connect to database and sanitize incoming $_GET variables
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_GET['e']);
    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_GET['p']);
    // Evaluate the lengths of the incoming $_GET variable
    if($id == "" || strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($e) < 5 ){
        // Log this issue into a text file and email details to yourself
        header("location: message.php?msg=activation_string_length_issues");
        exit(); 
    }
    // Check their credentials against the database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND email='$e' AND password='$p' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // Evaluate for a match in the system (0 = no match, 1 = match)
    if($numrows == 0){
        // Log this potential hack attempt to text file and email details to yourself
        header("location: message.php?msg=Your credentials are not matching anything in our system");
        exit();
    }
    // Match was found, you can activate them
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET activated='1' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    // Optional double check to see if activated in fact now = 1
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // Evaluate the double check
    if($numrows == 0){
        // Log this issue of no switch of activation field to 1
        header("location: message.php?msg=activation_failure");
        exit();
    } else if($numrows == 1) {
        // Great everything went fine with activation!
        header("location: message.php?msg=activation_success");
        exit();
    }
 else {
    // Log this issue of missing initial $_GET variables
    header("location: message.php?msg=missing_GET_variables");
    exit(); 
}}
?>
<!-- ********************************** -->
<!-- *********** message.php ********** -->
<!-- ********************************** -->
<?php
$message = "";
$msg = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9.:_()]#i', '', $_GET['msg']);
if($msg == "activation_failure"){
    $message = '<h2>Activation Error</h2> Sorry there seems to have been an issue activating your account at this time. We have already notified ourselves of this issue and we will contact you via email when we have identified the issue.';
} else if($msg == "activation_success"){
    $message = '<h2>Activation Success</h2> Your account is now activated. <a href="login.php">Click here to log in</a>';
} else {
    $message = $msg;
}
?>
<div><?php echo $message; ?></div>
<!-- ********************************** -->
<!-- ********* randStrGen.php ********* -->
<!-- ********************************** -->
<?php
function randStrGen($len){
    $result = "";
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$$$$$$$1111111";
    $charArray = str_split($chars);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
        $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

is it possible to rewrite so different modules interact?

Comment: `can you combine mysqli and PDO style programs?` at the same time? No. On different requests, yes.  And if you're doing ajax from the same page back to itself you're doing it completely wrong. Break it into distinct files.

Comment: @developerwjk Disagree. It works just fine and though separate files wuold be good practise, who's to say it's wrong.

Comment: ty @Adelphia and developerwjk. good advice. Would make sense to keep distinct file stles seperate. Very new at this PHP languae. teaching myself.... learning with mysql... only to find it depreciated. Best to learn many different angles at once :)

Comment: @developerwjk i am JUST learning some ajax with php. Any hints on tutorials would be greatly appreciated.